# How do I check that a particular template parameter is the same

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a class with three template parameters:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Unit;
```

Then I have a concept representing this class and all its specialization:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_unit : std::false_type {};

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct is_unit<Unit<A, B, C>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_unit_v = is_unit<T>::value;

template <typename T>
concept Unit_T = is_unit_v<T>;
```

In the definition of the Unit class, I want a function that returns a Unit with a different specialization from the one through which the function is called. I want the user to provide the desired return type. I have this working so far:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Unit {
public:
    // Other member stuff...

    template<Unit_T U>
    U as() { return U(*this); }
}

Unit<MyType, long double, MyOtherType> unit;
// Do stuff to unit.
auto unit2 = unit.as<Unit<MyType, long int, AnotherType>();
```

That all works as expected. There's one more requirement, however, that I can't figure out how to implement. The first template parameter of the desired type must match the first template parameter of the type through which it was called. So this:

```
Unit<MyType, long double, MyOtherType> unit;
// Do stuff to unit.
auto unit2 = unit.as<Unit<YetAnotherType, long int, AnotherType>();
```

should not compile.

I would think that the correct way to do this would look something like:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Unit {
public:
    // Other member stuff...

    template<Unit_T U>
    requires std::is_same_v<U<D>, D>
    // or maybe std::is_same_V<U::D, D> ?
    U as() { return U(*this); }
}
```

But that doesn't work. And, as I understand, even if that was the right way to require a template parameter be the right type, I can't further constrain a concept.

I tried writing another concept for a Unit with a specific first template parameter:

```
template<typename U, typename D>
concept UnitFirstType = is_unit_v<U> && std::is_same_v<U<D> /* or U::D */, D>;
```

But that doesn't work.

The problem seems to lie in how I'm using std::is_same_v. I just don't know how to use it with a template parameter.

So what is the proper way to achieve this:

```
Unit<MyType, long double, MyOtherType> unit;
auto unit2 = unit.as<Unit<MyType, long int, AnotherType>(); // will compile
// auto unit3 = unit.as<Unit<YetAnotherType, long int, AnotherType>(); // should not compile
```

Comment: Probably not the best way to do it, but the answer you’re looking for is that the function with U needs to be a template template parameter . (That wasn’t a typo) and then you can access the inner types. Another way to do it is to expose the types in the class through members.

Comment: Adding `using AType = A;` to the definition of my Unit class let me do `template<Unit_T U> requires std::is_same_v<typename U::AType, A> U as() { return U(*this); }`. This works here - I can edit my Unit class, and it will probably be convenient to have that member anyway - but what if I can't edit the class I'm working with. How would I write the template template version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what you want

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Unit;

template<typename U, typename A>
constexpr bool unit_first_type = false;

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
constexpr bool unit_first_type<Unit<A, B, C>, A> = true;

template<typename U, typename A>
concept UnitFirstType = unit_first_type<U, A>;

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Unit {
 public:
  // Other member stuff...
  template<UnitFirstType<A> U>
  U as();
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5bharnPbT)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can use the good-old (pre C++20) SFINAE.

For example, given a custom type traits as follows

```
template <typename, typename>
struct firstEqual : public std::false_type
{};

template <typename A, typename B1, typename C1, typename B2, typename C2>
struct firstEqual<Unit<A, B1, C1> const, Unit<A, B2, C2> const>
   : public std::true_type
{};
```

you can enable/disable `as()` as follows

```
template <typename U>
std::enable_if_t<firstEqual<Unit<A, B, C> const, U const>::value, U>
   as() { return U{}; }
```

Observe the use of `const`, to accept the case of different `Unit`s with different constness but the same first template argument... just in case is what do you want.

Observe also that you don't need the `Unit_T` concept any more.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Unit;

template <typename, typename>
struct firstEqual : public std::false_type
{};

template <typename A, typename B1, typename C1, typename B2, typename C2>
struct firstEqual<Unit<A, B1, C1> const, Unit<A, B2, C2> const>
   : public std::true_type
{};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
class Unit {
  public:
    // Other member stuff...

    template <typename U>
    std::enable_if_t<firstEqual<Unit<A, B, C> const, U const>::value, U>
       as() { return U{}; }
};



int main()
{
  Unit<int, long double, void> unit;

  auto unit2 = unit.as<Unit<int, long, float>>();  // compile
  //auto unit3 = unit.as<Unit<char, long, float>>(); // compilation error
}
```

Comment: Well, I have access to a c++20 capable compiler, and I'm already using constraints and concepts, so I don't see any reason to revert to "good-old" SFINAE. I would like some elaboration on your use of const, though.